# Partial function for trait implementation in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a Trait and its implementation, within which I want to reuse an existing function in a concise way. Here is the example:

```
object Util {
  def foo(a: Int, b:Int): Int = {// some implementation}
}
trait Animal {
  def eat(a: Int, b: Int): Int
}
object Dog extends Animal {
  import Util._
  def eat(a: Int, b:Int): Int = foo(a, b)
  /* Is this any concise way for the above? 
   * For example, I am looking for something 
   * like this to work:
   */
  // def eat = foo
  // def eat = foo(_, _)
  // val eat = foo(_, _)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*If* you simply wanted `eat` to be the same as `foo`, you could list the method `foo` into a function, and assign it to `eat`.

```
def foo(a: Int, b: Int): Int = ???
val eat = foo _
```

But it is not possible to use this approach when implementing a method from a trait like `Animal`. You must explicitly define the parameters of `eat` in `Dog`, which leaves you with:

```
def eat(a: Int, b: Int): Int = ???
```

I can't think of anything more concise and clear than `foo(a, b)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use eta-expansion as so:

```
val eat = foo _
val eat = foo(_, _) //equivalent
```

You can read more about eta-expansion on [this blog post](https://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/functional-scala-turning-methods-into-functions/).  This way, `eat` will have type `(Int, Int) => Int`.  You can also do:

```
val eat = (foo _).curried
```

To get make `eat` have type `Int => (Int => Int)`.  You can read more about `curried` [here](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/30/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-11-currying-and-partially-applied-functions.html).

You should note, too, that your use of the phrase "partial function" isn't how it is usually used.  Partial functions in Scala (and generally) are functions that aren't necessarily defined on the entire domain.  For example, in Scala:

```
val foo: PartialFunction[Int, String]  = { case 1 => "hello"; case 2 => "world" }
foo(1) //"hello"
foo.isDefinedAt(3) //false
foo(3) // exception
```

You can read more about partial functions in the docs [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction).